# Error in http SMS API

Tags: php, api, sms

I am integrating this SMS API in Travel Genie,[http://www.travelgenieapp.com](https://www.cannyinfotech.com) , which is a travel software.When the user is reaching the location, we send the SMS.

```
http://sms.cannyinfotech.com/sendsms.jsp?user=(xxxxxx)&password=(xxxxxxx) &mobiles=9659051538&sms=MESSAGE&unicode=0&senderid=CMREDU &version=3
```

I am using the below PHP code :

```
<?php

//Code using curl
//Change your configurations here.
//---------------------------------
$username = "amitpro";
$api_password = "demo1234";
$sender = "sender";

$domain = "sms.cannyinfotech.com";
$priority = "1"; // 1-Normal,2-Priority,3-Marketing
$method = "POST";
//---------------------------------

if (isset($_REQUEST['send'])) {

    $mobile = $_REQUEST['mobile'];

    $message = $_REQUEST['message'];

    $username = urlencode($username);
    $password = urlencode($password);
    $sender = urlencode($sender);
    $message = urlencode($message);

    $parameters = "user=$username&password=$api_password&senderid=$sender&mobiles=$mobile&sms=$message&unicode=0&version=3";

    $url = "http://$domain/sendsms.jsp?";

    $ch = curl_init($url);

    if ($method == "POST") {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $parameters);
    } else {
        $get_url = $url . "?" . $parameters;

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $get_url);
    }

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);  // DO NOT RETURN HTTP HEADERS 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  // RETURN THE CONTENTS OF THE CALL
    $return_val = curl_exec($ch);


    if ($return_val == "")
        echo "Process Failed, Please check domain, username and password.";
    else
        echo "$return_val";
}

echo "<form name='f1' method='post'>";

echo "<p> Mobile: <input name='mobile' > </p>";

echo "<p> Message: <textarea name='message' ></textarea> </p>";

echo "<p> <input type='submit' value='Send' name='send'></p>";

echo "</form";
?>
```

I am getting an error on the above PHP.
Can someone suggest an alternate PHP code?

The above code is given by [Canny Infotech.](https://www.cannyinfotech.com)

Comment: You forgot to give the details of the error. `echo "</form";` is incorrect.

Comment: Please include the error- make sure that you're providing a [MCVE].